# Developing a plug-in to charge for

Tags: plugin-development

Perhaps I'm not using the right search terms but I can't find how to develop a WordPress plugin that I want to make available on a subscription or purchase plan. When I try to Google this topic, woocommerce fills up all of the search results. I'm looking for how other developers disable their plugins for non-payment for example so I assume their is a database hook I can make to call home or something?

I've googled, "how to code a WordPress plugin that I want to sell" and all I get back are marketing tips. While those links are good, it's not what I am after at this time.

Comment: "how other developers disable their plugins for non-payment for example " They don't. And since WordPress plugins are GPL by necessity, you're not allowed to. What plugin developers do is only offer updates and support for paying customers.

Comment: So what stops one developer from taking someone else's plugin, modifying (fixing bugs, making enhancements, etc)? Or is this just an honor system?

Comment: Nothing. It's the whole point of the license. WordPress itself started as a fork of another platform, and WooCommerce is also a fork of a different plugin.

Comment: @JacobPeattie - I wasn't aware of all of this, thanks for the enlightenment. I guess I'll need to rethink if my piddly little plugin is actually worth the hassle then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet so I'll comment here.

Start here:

https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/self-hosted-plugin-update.html

That'll give you the basics.  Hope you realize the can of worms you're getting into... payment gateway api's, registration codes, managing updates, etc.  Self-hosting a plugin on your own is not for the feint of heart.

I know a number of years ago there was a company that took care of a lot of that for you, including registration & payments.  Can't seem to find them now though.

*edit* found them.  https://freemius.com/

Comment: LOL - I literally just purchased a plugin from a developer through this host.

Comment: To answer an above question, there's nothing preventing you from stealing someone else's premium plugin except...  Names and images used in those plugins can be copyrighted and trademarked.  So, you'd have to completely change those. Then, you'd have the problem of trying to out-market someone who's already established.  As stated above, WP and WooCommerce did just that.  The thing you can and must give premium customers is great customer support and regular updates.

Comment: Is it ethical to take someone else's plugin and modify it? For example, I purchased a plugin for a staff listing feature for a customer site. The output that is displayed on the visitor site is perfect but the administration area is waaaaay unorganized and too hodge-podge that my client doesn't like the UI. If I removed some of the menu links and modified it to only display the features my customer actually uses, is this ethical? On top of that, if I renamed the plugin so that a future update doesn't break the changes I made, is that ethical?

Comment: That depends on you.  From a legal standpoint, if it shares the GPL or similar license, you can do as you wish. Just don't reuse anything that might be considered trademarked or copyrighted.  As for the ethics, you have to decide. We could debate that for pages.  By the way, if you consider this to be the answer, please upvote  it. I need the points so I can leave comments. Thanks

Comment: I did contact the developer and he said no problem at all (via email) and stated he was glad it helped.

Comment: An honorable solution!  Thanks for the upvote.