# how to handle premium features in a wordpress plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, membership, encryption, plugin-members

I am developing a plugin in wordpress. I have a question regarding the premium features. How we can manage premium features between free and paid membership?

Are those features already part of plugin but disabled and once payment is made we just enable it? But then what if an average wp plugin developer like me crack those features ?

Is there some kind of encryption used?

I am more interested in saas type of membership. So there has to be a secure key generated to unlock the features. And obviously then features will be disabled again once membership closed or cancelled.

I guess it may be basic question but a big help for me. I would appreciate your support.

Thanks.

Comment: WordPress plugins must be licensed under the GPL, so encrypting the code or preventing it from working without a purchase are both forbidden. You should just look at what other plugins are doing. They either sell the extra features as a separate plugin, or a separate version of the plugin with more features. Buying just gives the user access to the download, and licenses are only used to allow the user to receive updates delivered from a private server, and entitles them to support.

Comment: This has been answered numerous times: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/365439/developing-a-plug-in-to-charge-for/365518

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I got my answer. Freemius can a good option.